# regex lookahead problems with greedy quantifier

Tags: regex, greedy, regex-lookarounds, quantifiers

Need to support the following formats

3 digits followed by optional space followed by three non-repeating characters specified within the following character set ACERV (space is valid only between the two characters)

Valid formats:

```
123
123 A
123 A v
123 CER
```

Invalid formats:

```
123A
123 AA
123 A  - when followed by a space
```

What I have so far - I might be over complicating this with lookaheads that are not necessarily required:

```
^([0-9]{3})                                         # - first 3 digits
 (\s(?=[ACERV]))([ACERV])                           # - allow space only when followed by ACERV
 (?!\3)(?=[ACERV ]{0,1})([ACERV ]{0,1})             # - do not allow 1st char to repeat
 (?!\3)                                             # - do not allow 1st char to repeat
 (?!\4)                                             # - do not allow 2nd to repeat
 (?!\s)                                             # - do not allow trailing space
 (?=[ACERV]{0,1})([ACERV]{0,1})|[0-9]{3}$
```

When the lookahead (?!\4) is added it fails to match on the valid format 123 A - modifying the quantifier on (?!\4) to (?!\4)* or (?!\4)? allows 123 A to match but allows 1st or 2nd char to be repeated.

Comment: why is 123A invalid?

Comment: Non-repeating adjacent or anywhere ?

Comment: Non-repeating only format in text field (i.e. only a single entry of 123 AEV would be allowed)

Comment: Does this need to be pure regexp?

Comment: I don't understand your rules. You say the space is optional, yet "123 A" is valid, and "123A" is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure of the requirements, this works on your samples.

```
 # ^(?i)\d{3}(?:[ ](?:([ACERV])[ ]?(?![ACERV ]*\1)){1,3}(?<![ ]))?$

 ^                      # BOL
 (?i)                   # Case insensitive modifier
 \d{3}                  # 3 digits
 (?:                    # Cluster grp, character block (optional)
      [ ]                    # Space, required
      (?:                    # Cluster grp
           ( [ACERV] )            # (1), Capture single character [ACERV]
           [ ]?                   # [ ], optional
           (?!                    # Negative lookahead
                [ACERV ]*              # As many [ACERV] or [ ] needed
                \1                     # to find what is captured in group 1
                                       # Found it, the assertion fails
           )                      # End Negative lookahead
      ){1,3}                 # End Cluster grp, gets 1-3 [ACERV] characters
      (?<! [ ] )             # No dangling [ ] at end
 )?                     # End Cluster grp, character block (optional)
 $                      # EOL
```

***update -***  Adjusted to replace lookbehind.

```
 # ^(?i)\d{3}(?!.*[ ]$)(?:[ ](?:([ACERV])[ ]?(?![ACERV ]*\1)){1,3})?$

 ^                      # BOL
 (?i)                   # Case insensitive modifier
 \d{3}                  # 3 digits
 (?! .* [ ] $ )         # No dangling [ ] at end
 (?:                    # Cluster grp, character block (optional)
      [ ]                    # Space, required
      (?:                    # Cluster grp
           ( [ACERV] )            # (1), Capture single character [ACERV]
           [ ]?                   # [ ], optional
           (?!                    # Negative lookahead
                [ACERV ]*              # As many [ACERV] or [ ] needed
                \1                     # to find what is captured in group 1
                                       # Found it, the assertion fails
           )                      # End Negative lookahead
      ){1,3}                 # End Cluster grp, gets 1-3 [ACERV] characters
 )?                     # End Cluster grp, character block (optional)
 $                      # EOL
```

Comment: This looks promising trying all variations before marking as answered

Comment: Any chance you could comment the following section: (?!(?:[ACERV ](?<![ ]{2}))*\1)){1,3}(?<![ ]))?

Comment: @DavidBrown - Removed an unneeded assertion, added comments.

Comment: Any chance I could get the regex to validate on the client side. I was testing in csharp and now when added to the client it errors in the javascript function RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid. It looks like the negative look behind is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about the regex

```
^\d{3}(?:$|\s)(?:([ACERV])(?!\1)|\s(?!$|\1))*$
```

will match the strings

```
123
123 A
123 A V
123 CER
```

See how the regex mathces at http://regex101.com/r/mW5qZ9/9

- `^` anchors the regex at the begining of the string
- `\d{3}` matches 3 occurence of any digit
- `(?:$|\s)` matches end of string `$` or space , `\s`
- `(?:\s?([ACERV])(?!\1)){0,3}` matches non repeating character from `[ACERV]`

  - `(?: )` non capturing group
  - `\s?` optional space
  - `([ACERV])` matches the characters in the class
  - `(?:([ACERV])(?!\1)|\s(?!$|\1))` asserts that the regex is not followed by `\1`, recently captured character. ensures that the characters are non repeating.

    - `(?!\1)` asserts that the character class cannot be followed by repeating character
    - `\s(?!$|\1))` asserts that if it is a space, then it cannot be followed by an end of string or repeating character from `\1`
  - `{0,3}` quantifier specifying the minimum occurence as zero and maximum occurence as 3
- `$` anchors the regex at the end of the string.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by #matched by your definition... I might not have specified it very well in the initial question. The space after the digits is required when followed by the optional characters. So 123A should not match.

Comment: @DavidBrown corrected in the answer. Hope it matches fine now

Comment: Now it does not match 123 A V

Comment: ignore previous comment it appears that it allows any number of spaces (i.e.) 123\b\b\bA or 123\b\b\bA\b\b\b\bV - should only allow a single space

Answer (score 0):

One plan is a simple regexp to pull apart the string, then a second step to validate that the characters are not repeating.

```
// check all characters in a string are unique,
// by ensuring that each character is its own first appearance
function unique_characters(str) {
    return str.split('').every(function(chr, i, chrs) {
        return chrs.indexOf(chr) === i;
    });
}

// check that the code is valid
function valid_code(str) {
    var spacepos = str.indexOf(' ');
    return unique_characters(str) &&
        (spacepos === -1 || (spacepos === 1 && str.length === 3));
}

// check basic format and pull out code portion
function check_string(str) {
    var matches = str.match(/^\d{3} ?([ACERV ]{0,3})$/i);
    valid = matches && valid_code(matches[1]);
    return valid;
}

>> inputs = ['123', '123 A', '123 A v', '123 CER', '123A', '123 AA', '123 A ']
[true, true, true, true, true, false, false]
```

The fourth test case shows as valid, because if the space is indeed optional, then there if `123 A` is valid then it would seem `123A` would be valid as well.

A possible advantage of this kind of approach is that if additional validation rules are introduced, they can be implemented more easily than mucking around inside a huge regexp.